# How to store an array in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

i have this session variable that hold an array which stores the current products in the cart,after a customer has choose from the list of product.

this is the array.

```
echo $_SESSION['cart'];

OUTPUT:
Array (
 [5] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 [price] => 45.00 )

 [7] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 [price] => 18.00 ) 
 ) 1
```

this array shows that there are two items in the cart  with products id's 5 and 7 receptively with there quantities ordered and the price of the product.

I would want to save this array in table where I can save and recollect this info. thank you

Comment: You could always serialize the array into a specific column in a table, but I wouldn't recommend it. I think what you're trying to is more a databasedesign-related issue. I would have created a table called like orders and put the data into that table (and have column for price, a column for quantity etc). That would be more flexible and is a far better approach in my opinion.

Comment: could you help a little more by explaining your method please

Comment: I have posted an answer just for explaining my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
$varible = serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
```

And store it in a `VARCHAR` TYPE

And When you returning data use `unserialze`

Comment: thanks very much it work for me but one last problem  how wud i be able to take out  the values out the array to do some calculation.  example inoder to get my subtotal for each product i have to multiply the quantity by the price . and the in order to get the grand total i have to add all the subtotals to get the grand total.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = serialize($_SESSION['cart']);
```

This should work ;)

Comment: That will not store it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really store all values for the product in array in a column in a table.

I would create a table to store orders made.

**order-table:**

```
orders

order_id (primary key)
product_id (reference to which product it is in products-table)
quantity
price (price when purchased the product)
```

Based on the session you have:

```
Array (
 [5] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 [price] => 45.00 )

 [7] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 [price] => 18.00 ) 
 )
```

If 5 and 7 is your actual productids, then you should store the values something like this in orders-table:

```
INSERT INTO orders (product_id, quantity, price) VALUES (5, 1, 45000);
INSERT INTO orders (product_id, quantity, price) VALUES (7, 1, 18000)
```

If you have a product that costs 45.50 you should store it like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (product_id, quantity, price) VALUES (5, 1, 45500);
```

**The reason why this is a better approach is that is far more easy to extract information about any order later on**. (for example to return all sales for a specific product)

If you then want to get the total for a specific order, just do a SQL:

`SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE order_id = 14` (example for order 14)

If you want to return all values for the order, you just do like:

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = 14` (example for order 14)

Comment: okay initial that was my target, so i decided to take out the values using [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)  from the array but i wasnt getting the results i was expecting that why i decided to store the whole array. if there is a way to take out the values from the array so i can stored them like how you are explaining please teach me

Comment: It's just to use some basic SQL. I've updated my question with an example